# ServletRegistration.Dynamic? How can there be a dot in an Interface name?

Tags: java, syntax

I found this while reading about programmatic configuration of servlets:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic addServlet(String name, String servletClass)
```

This one: **ServletRegistration.Dynamic** baffles my core Java syntax knowledge. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a *static nested* interface. It has been defined in the source code as

```
public interface ServletRegistration {

  public static interface Dynamic {
    // ..
  }
  // ..
}
```

Read more about [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). The concepts apply to *interfaces* as well.

> Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

Also, take a look at this SO link: [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation on [ServletRegistration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html)

There you can see Dynamic is a [nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html), `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` is a [sub interfac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3)e of `Interface ServletRegistration`

`public static interface ServletRegistration.Dynamic extends ServletRegistration, Registration.Dynamic`

`What does it mean?`

It means that return type of `addServlet` is `ServletRegistration.Dynamic`

`And how is this possible?`

This was possible but `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` is a sub-interface.